# mysql_stmt_fetch not returning results?

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to fetch records from a table, here is the code

```
    $mysqli = connect();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contact_by = ?";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare( $query );
    print_r( $this->user_id );
    $stmt->bind_param( 'i', $this->user_id );
    $stmt->execute()
    $list = array(); 
    while( $row = $stmt->fetch() )

    {
        $contact = new data( $row );
        $list[] = $contact;
        print_r($list);
    }
    $mysqli->close();
    return $list;
```

$row returns '1'.

Comment: What is `connect();`?

Comment: it is returning mysqli object

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it doesn't.

If you bother to read [the manual page for this function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php), you will be aware of what does it return and how it works in general.

And of the function [get_result()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) as well, which you actually need

Comment: get_result() undefined error shows up. I used pdo for earlier projects, this is for the first time i am using mysqli. They are different.

Comment: This is horror, i am shifting back to PDO.